# jQuery JSON.parse after split

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var text = $('textarea'),
        select = $('button');


    select.click(function(e){

            if ($('input').val().indexOf('add') !== -1) {

                var 
                    t = $('input').val().split('add'),
                    A = $M(JSON.parse(t[0])),
                    B = $M(JSON.parse(t[1])),
                    a = A.add(B);

                if( a == null) {text.val('error'); return false;}
                //[ [2, 1], [3, 4] ]add[ [2, 4], [5, 4] ]
                text.val(a.toSource().slice(11,a.toSource().length-2))
            }
            return false;


    });

});
```

I have problem with this code. The JSON parser throws an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] . Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It's sylvester.js for matrix

Comment: What's in the $('input') field?. The JSON string in there could be malformed.

Comment: It will have something like : [ [2, 1], [3, 4] ]add[ [2, 4], [5, 4] ]

Comment: try `console.log(t[0])` and `console.log(t[1])` to see what you get after split.